# JavaScript: Too much recursion?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript through *Eloquent JavaScript* and one of the exercises is to write a recursive function, `isEven`, that returns true if a number is even or false if a number is odd.

If I understood correctly, the author specifically wanted the following to be implemented:

1. If a number == 0, then it is even.
2. If a number == 1, then it is odd.
3. "For any number N, its evenness is the same as N-2".

But when I use the code I have below, I get an error: `InternalError: too much recursion (line 3 in function isEven) …` How can I fix this while still using a recursive function?

```
// Your code here.
function isEven(n){
  if(n==0){
    return true;
  }
  else if(n==1){
    return false;
  }
  else{ 
    n = n-2; 
    isEven(n);  
  }  
}

console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-1));
// → ??
```

Comment: You're missing `return` in the `else` block. Use `return isEven(n);`

Comment: Both of the conditions will never be true with negative starting value ...

Comment: if it is negative make it position and solve.

Comment: @Tushar Good catch, thank you. And yes, you guys are right. I should have checked for negative numbers.

Comment: Be aware that with the recursive definition if you give it a large enough number it will indeed "run out of stack space".  As a training exercise that's fine, but illustrates a point in the "real world" use of recursion that you must always bear in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another check, before decrementing/incrementing a value.

```js
function isEven(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        n = n - 2;
    } else {
        n = n + 2;
    }
    return isEven(n);
}

console.log(isEven(50));
console.log(isEven(75));
console.log(isEven(-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle it recursion with that function, the value needs to be its absolute value.

```js
console.log("isEven");

function isEven(n) {
  //Ensure that we look at the numbers absolute value
  n = Math.abs(n);
  //Do a loop instead of recursion
  if (n == 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (n == 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    n = n - 2;
    return isEven(n);
  }
}
console.log(isEven(50));
console.log(isEven(75));
console.log(isEven(-1));
console.log("fasterIsEven");
//A faster way that eliminates recursion
function fasterIsEven(n) {
  return n % 2 === 0;
}
console.log(fasterIsEven(50));
console.log(fasterIsEven(75));
console.log(fasterIsEven(-1));
```

Javascript has a build-in method to test if something is dividable with something else, called modulus (`%`). This method is faster, but not recursive.

Comment: If you really want that last bit of performance, replace the `%` with a `&`. This is a bitwise and, which is a lot faster than the costly modulo that JS uses for floating point numbers!

Answer (score -1):

`function IsEven(n){ return n%2 === 0 }`

The core code is this one
`return n%2 === 0`

In order to increase the program's strength, it is recommended to increase non-number decisions.

Comment: That's no longer a recursive function.

Comment: It has to be recursion, right? Even if it's inefficient?

Comment: Yupp. I believe the point of this exercise is to teach recursion. Your method is clearly way more efficient, only it doesn't solve the matter at hand :)

Comment: First, I suggest you change it，`return isEven(n%2);`
Second,Other types of (float),
thrid, swich Instead of if

Comment: Well I believe to teach recursion, it's better to use a concept that is easier to solve via recursion like iterating through trees, rather than teaching bad coding practices like using recursion where it's not needed.